# How can i change backgrounds between frames in '2D animation' workspace?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I'm currently working on a 2D animation project on blender,which is the first time ever i've use grease pencil and the 2D animation workspace.

Here i just simply add the background as a plane into the scene:
[image]

But when the animation keeps playing i don't know how to change to another background:

[image]

In other animation software i just simply put the background into a layer and that's that.But blender seems blow all of that concept out of my head.Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way would be to do this:

- Create your second background as another plane anywhere out of camera, then create a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd> > `Location` for both planes on the last frame before you change shot.
- Go forward one frame (so to the first frame of your new shot), move the first background out of the way and put the second background in place, then create another location keyframe for both background planes.
  Note that you should be in object mode to do these steps.

**But**, a much better way would be to use two separate scenes and cut between them using the VSE as explained in [this](https://youtu.be/9N-glGarYuM?t=4309) tutorial at around 1h11m. It's worth watching the whole thing if you're just starting with grease pencil.

Comment: Thanks alot, Blender is so complicated

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to simply change the image on the plane itself by making the material dynamic.

In the example below, I have 1 material on a plane containing 2 images, set to switch when the frame number reaches 125 (halfway). By inputting *#frame*  into the field of the Value Node, the value will keep up with the current frame as you are animating, allowing the "switch" to occur at whatever frame number you input into the Greater Than (Math) Node.

[image: Switch]